# How to open new screen on Samsung TV emulator?

Tags: javascript, html, css, samsung-smart-tv, television

I am working on Samsung TV application, so I made interning screen which tell the user some information about this application, after the user read the information he should click on welcome button to go to the main page.

So should I create a new html, then when I click on the button, a new page opening up?
Actually I was using this Technic in android applications!!!

So does this work on TV applications? If not, what should I do? Any advice will help, THANKS

Note: I study this code http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open4
but this function didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to have a base html like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="popup"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

And have your "screens" in separate html documents, and when you push a button, refresh your base html according, this way:

```
//on click 
$('#content').html('');
$('#content').load('mynewcontent.html');
```

Samsung applications work with single page web app philosophy, so you must refresh the base html dynamically.

If you need to create a popup, there are lots of tutorials about how to make a div looks like a popup (manipulating position absolute, width, height, adding a semi-transparent black background...).

Expect this give you a clue, there is a long time I worked with samsung tv's.

Comment: ooh.. thanks for your information, its really helped me.. i created a pop-up thing as a new screen... you are awesome.. i appreciate your help.. thanks ^^ @Chatyeux

Answer (score 0):

Samsung TV applications do not have windows or tabs, so you cannot use `open` to create a new one.

Render your message inside the existing page with DOM manipulation instead.